# Does Opera support NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall on Mac?

Tags: macos, opera, npapi

I'm trying my plugin with Opera 12.00 (MacOSX) and it seems like function NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall() does not work.
Is there any trick I'm missing, or the function is not supported?

The plugin works properly in Windows and in other browsers on Mac (with some workaround for Safari)

Answer (score 1):

NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall has never worked for me with Opera; for that matter, it doesn't work on Safari 5.1 either.

[FireBreath](http://firebreath.org) uses NSTimer to do a workaround.